# Javascript CHAR insert replicate keystroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror in a **mobile** project (using PhoneGap) and a particular CodeMirror function will initiate when the " > " key is pressed.

In my application i have a quick button that allows the user to insert a " > " without having to find it on their softkeyboard. The problem is that CodeMirror detects the keystroke and not the character code  *&#62;*.

So when the user presses the button - the code does not initiate because it never detected the keystroke.

jQuery:

```
$('.html-inp').click(function() { 
    var txt = $(this).text().toString();
    editor.replaceSelection(txt, focus);
    editor.focus();
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href='#' data-role='button' id='a1' class='html-inp'>&#62;</a>
```

Does anyone know how I can trick the app into thinking the key was pressed and not just inserting a character code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Tim Down is right, I seem to have overlooked the *character code* in light of the key code. The `>` character has a `charCode` of `62`, which is also what's sent in the jQuery event object's `which`, `keyCode`, and `charCode` properties. I've made appropriate changes below:

Try the following HTML:

```
<a href='#' data-role='button' id='a1' class='html-inp' data-char='62'></a>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('.html-inp').click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress'),
        char = $(this).data('char');
    e.shiftKey = true;
    e.which = char;
    e.charCode = char;
    e.keyCode = char;
    editor.replaceSelection(String.fromCharCode(char), focus);
    editor.trigger(e);
});
```

This should have the effect of inserting the bracket into the editor, and also triggering the `keypress` event on the editor so that the rest of your code can act accordingly.

Comment: If a keystroke produces a character, it has a character code associated with it, so your first sentence seems wrong, unless I'm misunderstanding your point.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I did a little more research and made edits. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This is in the right direction but I believe the last line needs a little rework. I cannot replaceSelection(char.... because char in this case equals 62. I tried replaceSelection(String.fromCharCode(char)... which inserted a ">" but it did not trigger the codemirror function.

Comment: Is `editor` a jQuery object? If not, you should clone it as a new jQuery object like `var $editor = $(editor);`, and then use `.trigger(e)` on the jQuery object. Otherwise, do you know **exactly which key event** your CodeMirror function is listening for? Is it `keypress`, `keydown`, or `keyup`?

Comment: Good question. I do not know. I'll try to see if I can dig through their manual. Thanks for the tip though.